# Go to Next Article - using finish() and startActivity(), but just loads new article on top

Tags: android, android-activity, reload

The title just about explains my entire problem.  I have a simple news app - scroll up and down to look at article headlines, then click one to go to the ArticleActvity (ie read the article).

When the user swipes left or right, it loads the next or previous article.  But - my code apparently just loads a new article activity on top of the other, because my back button, when clicked multiple times, will close the article activity, then close another, then close another....etc etc. until you finally get back to the list of articles.

As an Android noob, here's my code to 1) detect a horizontal swipe, and 2) reload (attempt) the same activity with a new article.

**Versions:**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

**My code in ArticleActivty.java:**

```
SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener()
{

     @Override
     public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
     {
         if(distanceX < -60)
         {
             //still need to hide article and show rotator graphic
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ArticleActivity.class);
             myIntent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(articlesDataSource.getNextOrPrevArticleId(article.id, true)));
             overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
             myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

             finish();

             overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
             startActivity(myIntent);
         }
         else if(distanceX > 60)
         {
             //still need to hide article and show rotator graphic
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ArticleActivity.class);
             myIntent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(articlesDataSource.getNextOrPrevArticleId(article.id, false)));
             overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
             myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

             finish();

             overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
             startActivity(myIntent);
         }
         return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
     }
```

Comment: add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in the `ArticleActivity's` tag of your manifest file

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem - makes for a slightly strange animation each time, but that does it!! Thank you!  Do you want to add that as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: I guess credit is a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

in the `ArticleActivity's` tag of your manifest file

Comment: I ended up using 'singleTask' instead of `singleInstance` - this seemingly allows me to click a photo that starts a new article, then still get back to the original article.